# Alternative to base64 when loading data from file-input

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I am currently reading a file using the HTML5 file input method.

When the file gets loaded, I grab it's `src` (after I define it as an `Image`) and put that src directly into the `background-image` property of a `div.`

I logged the src and it seems that it is a *Base64 string.*

**Unfortunately there is an issue with encoding files to base64 and low memory on Android phones(they hang the browser).**

> Is it possible not to encode it to Base64 when reading the file and
>   display it using an alternative, more memory efficient way?

---

This is what I currently use:

```
   function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                $("#alertBox").show();
                $("#alertBox").html("Oops! The link is NOT a valid image");
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#alertBox").hide()
                }, 3000);
                continue;
            }

            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var span = e.target.result;
                    uploadedImg = new Image();
                    uploadedImg.src = e.target.result;
                    uploadedImg.onload = function () {
                        changeSelectedImg(uploadedImg.src);//This is the function I use to change the background-image of a div with the src of the uploaded file, which is B64
                        proceedToView("2") 
                    }
                };
            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
}
```

Comment: you can kill the whole FileReader part and just use ... new Image().src=URL.createObjectURL(f); window.URLs are way faster than dataURLs, and you don't even have to mess with the async code.

Comment: @dandavis thanks, can you explain this a bit more in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use window.URL to create an object URL instead of a dataURL:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                $("#alertBox").show();
                $("#alertBox").html("Oops! The link is NOT a valid image");
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#alertBox").hide()
                }, 3000);
                continue;
            }
            var uploadedImg = new Image();
            uploadedImg.onload = function () {
               changeSelectedImg(uploadedImg.src);
               proceedToView("2") ;
            };//end onload
            uploadedImg.src = URL.creatObjectURL(f);
        }//next
}
```

this runs faster and looks cleaner than FileReader-based routines, as long as the browser supports window.URL: http://caniuse.com/#search=url

Comment: nice, thanks man - I'm no caniuse and I see that Android browsers need a prefix- webkit. I thought that prefix applied only to CSS, what does it have to do with this? I'm asking cause Android browsers are what I'm targeting

Comment: this shows up top of the code how to fallback to the webkit prefix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images , but it's just window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

Comment: also, you may want to call  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(strURL); from inside your changeSelectedImg() function, after you've assigned the url for the last time, to clear out the ram on long-running pages.